# How to handle a change in system level font size on iOS with React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

We have a situation where if a user decides to increase the "Larger Text" size in iOS Settings (see image below), it then messes up our view layouts in React Native, as the font size will now be larger.

For example here is a ListView row BEFORE changing the "Larger Text" setting in iOS system settings:

[image]

And here is the same row AFTER increasing the "Larger Text" setting:

[image]

What is best practice to handle such font scale increase in React Native ? This is obviously just one example, and there are other scenario's such as a View that only contains Text, but we do not want to increase the height of that View at runtime.

Appreciate anyone's advice on this, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following to block such changes (do it on your root js file):

```
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Comment: thats great thanks.  also-what about where we'd like to resize View(s) based on these font scale setttings ? how would we figure out how a View needed to (say) have it's height increased due to the user increasing the "large" font setting ? (in system Settings on iOS)

Comment: Should i need to add it inside the constructor in App.js?

Comment: You can even do it outside. However constructor should work too.

Comment: This is not a great option for accessibility!

Answer (score 0):

you could use ITEM_SIZE * PixelRatio.getFontScale()